# Returning error codes from Stored Procedure call c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, error-handling

I'm running a VS2013 project which requires me to connect to and run stored procedures on a SQL Server backend database. So in my app_code folder I've created a `SQLHelper` class:

```
public class SQLHelper
{
    private const string myConnSetting = "zDevConnection";

    public DataSet getSQLData(string mySQLStoredProcedure)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[myConnSetting].ConnectionString;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mySQLStoredProcedure);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cmd.Connection = cn;

            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ad.Fill(ds);

            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception BadSQL)
        {
            throw BadSQL;
        }
    }
}
```

So that in my controllers I can call and 'fill' datasets that I can use to do stuff with.

So.

```
    protected DataSet insertBlogEntry()
    { 
        SQLHelper mySQL = new SQLHelper();
        return mySQL.getSQLData("mydatabase.MySTPName");
    }
```

Which I call like this:

```
DataSet myEntry = insertBlogEntry(model.Email, model.Name, model.Company);
```

all is well and everything works 'ok' apart from where the stored procedure doesn't work as expected for example it throws back a controlled error message if I try to insert a duplicate record.

So what I'm trying to do is trap and return this error in my controller. I'm catching that there's been an error in my `SQLHelper` class but I don't know how to return this error back to my controller which is expecting a dataset and not a string.

Could anyone show me the light please?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Side note: Why do you catch `Exception BadSQL` if you don't do anything with it but attempt to rethrow it immediately?  And when you do `throw BadSQL;`, that's actually not the right way to rethrow an exception, because you'll lose the stack trace.  If you need to rethrow an exception, just do `throw;`.  But in this case, you don't even need to have the `try-catch` there.

Comment: Not sure that I'm understanding you there mate

Comment: Try changing throw BadSQL; to Exception.Message;

Comment: I think that the main problem that I have is that I'm attempting to fill a dataset and the 'badsql' or exeption.message is a string

Comment: i know this is years later, but sstan is saying this:  When you catch and rethrow an error the way you are here, the stack trace will say that this catch block is the origin of the exception.  You need to throw the actual exception's contents so that's preserved.

Answer (score 0):

It's me I'm being a raving dumbo, I should have wrapped the dataset myEntry =.... in the a try catch block

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  You already have ALL of your code in a try catch block.